# How to specify schema name in <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

Tags: spring-integration

We are using the below configuration to execute a Oracle Stored Procedure.  The stored proc (GET_FRMA) is in schema -> XX_EMPROC

We have a User -> XX_EMUSER that has been granted execute privilege on the stored proc.

I need to specify the schema name -> XX_EMPROC  in the below configuration.

```
    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
            id="outbound-gateway-storedproc-get-forma" data-source="dataSource"
            is-function="false"
            stored-procedure-name="GET_FRMA"
            expect-single-result="true">

        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="V_REF_ID" direction="IN" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="V_FRMA"   direction="OUT" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CLOB}"/>

        <int-jdbc:parameter name="V_REF_ID" expression="payload" />
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Please note that when datasource is created using user -> XX_EMPROC it works fine, but when we use user -> XX_EMUSER  we get the below error.

- Error:

**nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for 'GET_FRMA'"**

Comment: Did you try this : ` stored-procedure-name="XX_EMPROC.GET_FRMA"`? https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3348

Comment: Yes.. getting error. : error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0$child.outbound-gateway-storedproc-get-forma.handler]; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature for 'XX_EMPROC.GET_FRMA' - package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName(\"XX_EMPROC\")'

Comment: OK. How about `ignore-column-meta-data="true"` ?

Comment: now its working :) thanks a lot.. why is it able to find the proc now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To let it work you should specify the `stored-procedure-name` together with the schema name:

```
stored-procedure-name="XX_EMPROC.GET_FRMA"
```

But at the same time you have to specify:

```
ignore-column-meta-data="true"
```

That means:

```
<xsd:attribute name="ignore-column-meta-data" default="false" use="optional">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                If true, the JDBC parameter definitions for the stored procedure
                are not automatically derived from the underlying JDBC connection. In
                that case you must specify all Sql parameter definitions explicitly
                using the 'sql-parameter-definition' sub-element.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

That options is related to the `CallMetaDataContext` option:

```
/**
 * Specify whether call parameter metadata should be accessed.
 */
public void setAccessCallParameterMetaData(boolean accessCallParameterMetaData) {
    this.accessCallParameterMetaData = accessCallParameterMetaData;
}
```

Which turns out to the:

```
/**
 * Initialize the database specific management of procedure column meta data.
 * This is only called for databases that are supported. This initialization
 * can be turned off by specifying that column meta data should not be used.
 * @param databaseMetaData used to retrieve database specific information
 * @param catalogName name of catalog to use (or {@code null} if none)
 * @param schemaName name of schema name to use (or {@code null} if none)
 * @param procedureName name of the stored procedure
 * @throws SQLException in case of initialization failure
 * @see org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall#withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
 */
void initializeWithProcedureColumnMetaData(DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData, @Nullable String catalogName,
        @Nullable String schemaName, @Nullable String procedureName) throws SQLException;
```

That's why we have that JIRA ticket.

But on the other hand that automatic `columnMetaData` leads to the extra call to the DB and that is really not a fact that the result will be what you expect in your application. My recommendation to always switch off it. At least for Oracle.